# Java: Get hashmap value

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8

I've been looking over the internet but I cant seem to find this answer. I have a hashmap:

```
public Map<String, Integer> killstreaks = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Now I want to call the second value, the integer. SO by using the string as a reference, I know I can do this:

```
killstreaks.get(//idk)
```

I just need to get my head around on how to get the second value so I can use it to use a formula to work out a value to reward the player.

How it works is that the player kills someone and I store it in this, the player name and the streak they are on, as they kill I add 1 to the streak. When they kill someone I want to give them money according to their streak so I want to use the integer compared to the name, so if I provide the name, it gives the corresponding int, how do I get that? Thanks!

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to do...

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) it is. Maps are pairs key and value. getKey() getValue().

Comment: what do you mean with "second value" ?

Comment: There is the hashmap, it contains the string and the integer, i want to get the integers

Comment: You want to get the key of a value? Why?

Comment: @BallisticBlaze Do you want to get *all* the integers, or a specific one?

Comment: How it works is that the player kills someone and i store it in this, the player name and the streak they are on, as they kill i add 1 to the streak. When they kill someone i want to give them money according to their streak so i want to use the integer/streak, how do i get that?

Comment: @BallisticBlaze `killstreaks.get("someone")`

Comment: In what regard is your goal different from the action about which you already wrote “I know I can do this:…”?

Comment: @Biffen Thankyou, that did it! Please post it as the answer so i can give credit and future people can refer to it.

Comment: @BallisticBlaze No, I will not post it as an answer. It can be looked up in the documentation. This question should, in my view, be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can iterate over your [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : killstreaks.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    // continue here
}
```

To get a specific value (`Integer`) from your `Map` use:

```
killstreak.get("yourKey");
```

Seeing from your comment that you want to increment entries by 1, you can use:

```
killstreaks.put(key, killstreaks.get(key) + 1);
```

And as I see you are using Java 8 you can even use the nicer [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

```
killstreaks.put(key, killstreaks.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
```

Comment: It’s nice to know *one* new method of the new API, but it’s even better to learn also about the hundred others. If you want to increase the value of a specific key, you can just use [`map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and avoid the double hash lookup.

Comment: Thanks! i can use that to simplify my code @Holger